# Error saving a linear regression model with MLLib

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

Trying to save my linear regression model to disk I receive this error: "TypeError: save() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given"

> from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
>
> from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
>
> from pyspark.ml.regression import LinearRegression
>
> sc= SparkContext()
>
> lr = LinearRegression(featuresCol = 'features', labelCol='NextOrderInDays', maxIter=10, regParam=0.3, elasticNetParam=0.8)
>
> lr_model = lr.fit(train_df)
>
> lr_model.save(sc, "lr_model.model")

Searching the web outputs something similar to what I wrote. What do I miss as 3rd argument?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You use the ml package not the mllib: `from pyspark.ml.regression import LinearRegression`.

So the save function has only one argument: the path (cf. [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.regression.LinearRegression)).